# How to detect the current Backing Bean is no longer needed in a JSF application

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

My configuration: JSF 2.1/Java 7

What I want is to have my own CDI scope, so I can declare a backing bean like this:

```
@SpecialScoped(name="specialName")
public class SpecialBackingBean {
}
```

All the parts regarding declaring the new scope type `@SpecialScoped` is ok, so I can annotate my classes with that scope and keep track when a certain page references such a backing bean.

However, What I need now is to detect that the user is moving to another web page and another backing bean so I can decide that the current `@SpecialScoped` BackingBean should or not be destroyed.

Any help will greatly appreciated!

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by "context change"? You'll need to listen for some kind of event in order to recognize when to create/destroy your scope. It heavily depends on how broad your scope is planned to be. Should it survive multiple EL evaluations, multiple requests or even multiple views? In each case you'll need to elaborate what events are suitable to listen on.

Comment: "Context change" in my case means to have a web page depending on another backing bean, different than the one that is serving the current page. You talked about an relevant point: backing beans annotated with `@SpecialScoped` must survive while the application user is navigating among pages that reference backing beans annotated with `@SpecialScoped`. In the moment the user navigates to a page that references a backing bean not annotated with `SpecialScoped`, then all the so far existing backing beans must die.

Comment: This would sound problematic if you reference a `@RequestScope` and `@SpecialSope` bean within the same page. Did you elaborate the `javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped` ?

Comment: This sounds much like the default behavior of `@FlowScoped`. Why not using it?

Comment: Yes, ConversationScope does not give me exactly what I need, that's why I'm going to build my own scope kind. I have legacy applications that must be ported gradually from `@ViewScoped`backing beans to the new `@SpecialScoped` ones. So, during some time I will have both kind of scope.

Comment: @BalusC: absolutely correct!!! I can't use it because I can't upgrade to JSF to 2.2.

Comment: And what about the Deltaspike `@ViewAccessscoped`?

Comment: @Kukeltje: I'm not familiar with that, I´m going to check it out.

Comment: @Kukeltje: Indeed `@ViewAcessScoped` maybe will work to me. I'm going to perform some tests, but what @BalusC said is more what I was looking for. I would like to annotate my backing beans with something like `@SpecialScoped(name="businessProcess1"). All backing beans annotated with the same business process name would be kept alive until none of those backing beans were referenced anymore. So, I would be able to organize my beans in terms of business processes. It is indeed very similar to `@FlowScoped`.